# how to get the savefile function to run when button is clicked instead of on start

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, save

every time I open the file, savefile runs on start instead of on the button click. and when it does work it doesn't write in the file.

I tried to use lambda and got the error Function(self) is not defined. I thought it would make the func run when the button was pressed. but it did not,
this is the code I used

```
..................................................................
`import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from tkinter import messagebox

...................................................................
root = tk.Tk()
interface=tk.Tk
root.title("TEXTBOXER")
T = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=30)
...................................................................
def openfile():
    name = fd.askopenfilename() 
    print(name)
    if name !="":
        T.delete("1.0","end")
        f = open(name,"rt")
        T.insert(tk.END,f.read())
        f.close()

..................................................................

def Savefile(saving):
    save=fd.askopenfilename()
    print("saving file "+save)
    if save !="":
        print(save)
        f= open(save,'wt')
        print(saving)
        f.write(saving)
        print(save)
        f.close


.................................................................
def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit? (make sure to save)"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

................................................................
btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Save',
                command = Savefile(T.get))
btn.pack(anchor="nw",side="top")

btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'open',
                command = openfile)
.................................................................
# Set the position of button on the top of window
btn.pack(anchor="nw",side="top")



S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
T = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
tk.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Add `lambda :` before `Savefile`